# Why doesn't the Map size property update when I add a key/value pair using bracket notation?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-map

According to MDN, the [`size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/size) property of a `Map` object should represent the number of entries the `Map` object has. However, if I create an empty `Map` and use the bracket notation (not sure what the formal name for this is) to add a key/value pair, the `size` property is not updated. However, if I use the `Map.set(key, value)` function, then the property is updated. Why is this?

Example:

```
var ex = new Map();
ex['key1'] = 'value1';
ex.set('key2', 'value2');
```

After running this, `ex.size` returns `1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because adding a property to the map object is not the same as adding an element to the map (and vice versa). Try `ex.get('key1')` (and `ex['key2']`). Only `Map#set` adds an element to the map. Maybe it becomes clearer if you consider this poor and limited implementation of `Map`:

```
class Map {
  constructor() {
    this._items = {};
  }

  set(key, value) {
    this._items[key] = value;
  }

  get(key) {
    return this._items[key];
  }

  get size() {
    return Object.keys(this._items).length;
  }
}
```

Adding a property to an instance of the class would not affect `this._items`, which is where the map entries are stored.

---

You can add arbitrary properties to basically any object in JavaScript, but that doesn't mean that the object is doing anything with them.

The most confusing case is probably arrays. Only properties whose numeric value is between `0` and `2^32` are considered "elements" of the array. So when I do

```
var arr = [];
arr.foo = 42;
```

then `arr.length` will still be `0`.

Answer (score 2):

Because `ex['key1'] = 'value1';` just added a new property `key1` to the object `ex` (that happens to be of type `Map`).

It does not affect the content of the actual Map.